# Concatenating 2 columns with TimeStamp in JavaScript Add Method

Tags: 2013, jsom

I have a Save button and when user clicks it, I want a new value of concatenation of 2 columns with time stamp. Below is the image of the list. I want the Recipient column to be loaded with BillingDoc+Item+TimeStamp

[image]

```
function AddItem() {
var ListItem = web.get_lists().getByTitle('TracingList');
var itemCreationInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = ListItem.addItem(itemCreationInfo);
oListItem.set_item('Recepient', '??What Goes Here???');
oListItem.update();
context.load(oListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(ListQS, ListQF);

}
```

And i want to update 2 web parts at the same time with same information for 'n' number of items - it could be 1 item or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried doing this using SharePoint designer workflow which will create items in two other lists with this value on item created.